# How to use the brew version of a command (aws-es-proxy) instead of node?

Tags: npm, homebrew

I used `npm -i -g aws-es-proxy`. But I actually wanted to do `brew install aws-es-proxy` because the commands are slightly different for these two packages depending on whether installed with npm or brew. So I did `npm uninstall -g aws-es-proxy` and after uninstalling and deleting the folder that was still left over

```
$ cd /Users/USER_NAME/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/
$ ls
aws-azure-login node        npm     npx
bin USER_NAME$ rm -r aws-azure-login
```

I still would get

```
$ aws-es-proxy -listen :9200 -ENDPOINT
-bash: /Users/USER_NAME/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/aws-es-proxy: No such file or directory
```

It seems like this terminal is using npm version instead of brew version. Can you let me know how I can force to use the brew installation for this command?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all I had to do was open a new terminal session and it recognized the command. Not sure what behind the scenes stuff was happening.